# Bootstrap dropdown styling, weird behaviour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to change the background color and font-weight when I hover over an item in a drop-down menu.

When I use the 'a' selector I have no effect, when using the .link class it will get bolded but background color will not change. When I use #action I will have the desirable effect.

Why is it like that?

I preferably I would like to use the .dropdown > ul > li > a selector, how can I do that?

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ehall/4Xs2N/

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Switch between .link, #action and a -->
<style>
#action:hover{
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#" class="link" id="action" >Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#action:hover{
```

to

```
ul.dropdown-menu a:hover{
```

Comment: Thanks, but would you like to explain more? Why doesn't using .link class or 'a' selector work? ul.dropdown-menu a:hover works, but not .dropdown-menu ul a:hover?

Comment: I suggest using the CSS inspector to find out which other rule is overriding your rule.

Comment: How do I use the CSS inspector?